# Accidental notebook formatting?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

As I was trying to save my notebook by hitting `ctrl + s`, I might have hit a different letter by accident and something unexpected happened:

An extra row appeared below the menus at the top:

[image]

and the check-mark seems to now permanently be set in:

> Window -> Toolbar -> Formatting

(I tried clicking on it several times, but this check-mark never goes away.)

Worst of all, when creating a new cell, the cell now defaults to a Text cell instead of an input cell.

What happened here? Is there some way to revert my notebook to its original standard behavior?

EDIT:

Following suggestions in the answers, the EditBar is now gone, but all my calculation cells are still indented inward, while text cells are not indented, and creating a new cell also still defaults to a text cell instead of input. Any idea how to fix that?

Also, In: and Out: labels at the left are now grey and turn orange upon evaluation for some reason. This color scheme was not present before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is to use [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowToolbars] = Inherited
```

> {}

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps you also know how to make creating a new cell default to Input cell instead of text cell? (See my edit in the question.)

Comment: @Kagaratsch Are you sure you didn't change the stylesheet? What happens if you switch to the Default stylesheet?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out stylesheets! I looked it up and changing it back to Default made my notebook normal again. I don't know how it happened, maybe `ctrl+s` means 'change stylesheet' when Australian keyboard layout is selected?

Answer (score 4):

I would open the Option inspector, make sure that global preferences are selected, then navigate Notebook options → Display options.

You should be able to deselect the EditBar from Windows toolbars to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, the EditBar is now gone, but all my calculation cells are still indented inward, while text cells are not indented, and creating a new cell also still defaults to a text cell instead of input. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Kagaratsch, on my installation, the menu entry Format → Style has "Input" checked.  My default cell type is Input.